# Как поменять местами единицы и нули в двоичном представлении числа без перебора значений?

Tags: python, оптимизация, replace, str-replace, строки

я пробовал подобный код:

```
s = '01110'
s2 = ''
for i in s: # перебор всех значений
    if i == '1':
        s2 += '0'
    else:
        s2 += '1'
print(s)
```

но так как подобный код будет работать достаточно долго на подобных строках с большей длинной, данный способ не подходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще есть нативные питоновские функции для таких преобразований строк:

```
t = str.maketrans('01', '10')
print('01110'.translate(t))
```

Вывод:

```
10001
```

`maketrans` просто создаёт словарь, переводящий соответствующие символы одной строки в символы другой строки, там по сути коды символов внутри. Вот что находится в `t`:

```
{48: 49, 49: 48}
```

`48` - это код символа `0`, а `49` - код символа `1`.

Работает это в общем-то довольно быстро:

```
%%time
s = '01110' * 100_000
s1 = s.translate(t)
```

Вывод:

```
CPU times: user 1.08 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.08 ms
Wall time: 1.09 ms
```

Хотя оба варианта от MaxU на той же строке работают в 100 раз быстрее, если что, порядка 8 µs.

P.S. Ваш код работает долго из-за того, что вы плюсуете строки на каждом шагу цикла, при этом каждый раз создаётся новая строка всё большей длины. Такого метода однозначно нужно избегать в первую очередь.

Comment: Действительно так гораздо лаконичнее! Совсем забыл про "str. maketrans" )

Comment: @MaxU Да про них все забывают, я случайно вспомнил. Но какой он медленный по сравнению с вашими вариантами! Странно. Наверное из-за `ord` и `chr` внутри )

Answer (score 2):

Вариант решения без цикла:

```
res = bin(2**len(s) - 1 - int(s, 2))[2:]
```

Простой и быстрый вариант решения, используя работу со строками:

```
res = s.replace("1", "2").replace("0", "1").replace("2", "0")
```